# Is it possible to get gedit's External Tools plugin working with cygwin on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, gedit

I see that gedit has an External Tools plugin, but it is Unix only. Is there a way to get it working with cygwin on Windows? Or is there a windows alternative to External Tools?